# Why can not copy csv to SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to copy csv file into psql table, but I have this error message:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
> Where: COPY table_name, line 1, column datum: ""
> 1 statement failed.

I have create a csv file in shell script, where I create date, time like this:
my_date=$(date +%F)
my_time=$(date +%T)

An example row from csv file:

```
2021-04-29 08:29:22 130 226 59000000 7439822 cityA 2002
```

then from psql I try to copy data:

```
psql -U example -d postgres -c "COPY table_name FROM '/example/example.csv' DELIMITER ' ';"
```

As I understand something wrong with the date format.
In sql the first column is set to DATE, the second is set to TIME, the rest is TEXT, or INTEGER.

I have tried to insert only one row, or data, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(datum)
VALUES (2021-04-29)
```

And have this error:

```
ERROR: column "datum" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 36
```

How can I solve this?
Thx

Comment: Put the content, the date in this case, between quotes: '2021-04-29', otherwise it becomes a calculation. 2021 minus 4 minus 29...

Comment: @FrankHeikens: That explains the broken `INSERT` test. But `COPY` wouldn't evaluate expressions. Still a syntax error, but a different explanation ...

Comment: Can you show the table definition?

Comment: I create the csv table like this: echo "$my_date $my_time $a $b $c" >> example.csv

Comment: and sql table was created with this: CREATE TABLE table_name (
    datum DATE,
    ido TIME,
    alap INT,
    telek INT,
    ar INT,
    azonosito TEXT,
    varos TEXT,
    ev INT
   );

Comment: I could not replicate using `COPY` or `\copy`. Are you sure you are not including an empty string at beginning of line instead of date for some of the rows, per `COPY` error: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am not sure, when I checked, there was no empty string...

Comment: Hi everyone, thx for your help. This part is working. I have changed the syntax when creating my_date: my_date=$(date +%F)   -- this is not worked. I used this: 
my_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) -- this solved with echo